# error on rails server - cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

I have installed ruby 2.0 using rubyinstaller, devkit and rails 4.0 beta (all 32 bit) on my 64 bit windows (because ruby weirdly misinterprets 64 bit processor to be a 32 bit)

I have added sqlite3 binaries (downloaded separately) to my PATH.

When I run rails server command, i get the following error

C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:

I have tried the fix at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubyinstaller/gedIaMryCFQ to reinstall sqlite3 gem from source, but it fails with error cannot find sqlite3.

After hours of debugging I cannot fix this problem. This has totally broken my motivation to learn the infallible Ruby on Rails framework. Ruby was supposed to be easy! Can someone help?

Comment: This is not a ruby on rails problem or a ruby problem. As it is said in the message, the gem can not load the native sqlite3 library from your paths. Such errors are MS Windows problems mainly and not ruby, rails or sqlite.

Comment: Try with a Linux or Mac environment really. You will have less headaches to develop Rails.

Comment: disappointing reply...this is a ruby problem because rails should work out of the box after install, this is a gem/ruby configuration issue. why gem cannot find sqlite3 in my path (when every other program can find it) is gems problem, which is ruby's problem.

Comment: @Pigueiras i will try it on linux if it doesn't work out, but i wanted to get on learning rails quickly, and ruby boasts of rapid web development. I don't understand why is sqlite3 is such a big problem, with gem, native libs for ruby 1.8,1.9 are installed but not for version 2.0. This is the root of the problem. I have run rails 3 on ruby 1.92 before and never faced a problem.

Comment: @SumitJain Rapid web development doesn't mean an easy installation :).  I am tired of seeing this type of weird errors, and always are with Windows environments, that's why I always recommend to install another OS.

Comment: Has anyone actually come up with a solution?  I thought that's what the Stack in all about, and not a FanBoy vs Windows bashing platform.

I, for one, would like some help with an answer, and "switch OS" is NOT an answer!

Comment: I am facing the same problem. And don't get me started about linux. First of all it takes 3 hours to get all the packages and then you have to install the devel packages. this that.

Answer (score 2):

We had problems with version Ruby 2.0 on a Windows 64bit machine ("missing sqlite3_native") so we reverted to Ruby 1.93 and it worked.

Comment: brilliant, who could have thought of that, we reverted to 1.93 & it worked, who said 1.93 is broken...downvoted